# Hooking Unity3D up to Business objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just started playing with unity and it is pretty awesome. I have an application that needs to adjust the position of a warehouse robot based on real time data. Is there anything that would prevent me from accessing a business object, so that it may feed a script attached to a bot, positional information? I assume business objects would just be considered another asset?

Thanks
Harold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an external library you want to communicate with to handle the real-time data and robot control then write a [native plugin](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html).

If you want to communicate directly from Unity scripts you can use standard c# networking functions. Here's [one example](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15422/unity-project-and-3rd-party-apps.html#answer-15477) I found. Note that prior to Unity 5 .NET Sockets required a Unity Pro license.

Comment: ok, thanks! This gets going in the right direction.